# Download multiple .csv file separately generated by PHP Script

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am running PHP Script using CodeIgniter Framework to generate user's and it's devices informations; Two different files are generated with help of

`csv_from_result($user_query, $delimiter, $newline);`

function of `$this->load->dbutil();`.

When i use

`$this->load->helper('download');`

library to download above .csv file using

`force_download($user_file_name, $usercsvdata);`

function it downloads first .csv file only, the second file is not downloaded which is of User's Devices.

Please help me to Solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter has a Zip file library build in. In order to download multiple files at the same time, they have to be added to an archive, like a .zip file.

```
<?php

//.. get $usercsvdata and $devicecsvdata

$this->load->library('zip');
$this->zip->add_data('users.csv', $usercsvdata);
$this->zip->add_data('devices.csv', $devicecsvdata);
$this->zip->download($user_file_name);
```